# Element got removed after applying filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am applying filters to get the data of a particular field through a dropdown, but when I select any option the filter applied elements get removed. How can I resolve it?

HTML code:

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <div>
  <label>Country filter</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="countryFilter" />

  <label>Order by</label>
  <select ng-model="selectedOrder">
    <option ng-repeat="option in options">{{option}}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter:{loc : selectedOrder}">{{ detail.country }}</li>    
</ul>
</body>
```

JS code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

 // order by options
 $scope.options = ['1', '2', '3'];

 // all countries
 $scope.details = [{
  id:1, country:'Finland', address:'Mainstreet 2',detail:[{
  loc:'1'
}]
},{
id:2, country:'Mexico', address:'Some address',detail:[{
  loc:'2'
}]
},{
 id:3, country:'Canada', address:'Snowroad 45',detail:[{
  loc:'3'
 }]
}];
});
```

I want to filter through `options` and `loc` value. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write a custom filter.

Change your filter to: `filter:{detail: {loc:selectedOrder}}`

I added `<option value=""></option>` to the dropdown and set `$scope.selectedOrder = "";` in order to show all countries by default.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Jaydo/pen/dMOXLX)

Answer (score 0):

filter:{prop:value} returns objects which have property `prop` at first level, it does not watch in object deeper. (When usual filter without params does it)

Your objects in array `details` do not have 'loc' property. So nothing fits filter.

You can not filter by exact property of 2nd and deeper levels of object with standard angular filter. Implement your own or change data.